# Find values from one table in another and mark rows accordingly using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, join, datatable

i have a problem with orders [orders] and returns [returns]. I have a long list of orders with many columns one of them being an order number and another list of returns just with the orders that have been returned. So if an order has been returned it show up with the same order number in the list [returns].

I want to figure out which orders have been returned and somehow mark them. For example with adding a column "Returned" in the order list that would be marked "y".

any ideas how i could do this?

Example:

orders = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'OrderNo'],['John', 'Smith', 39],['Mary', 'Jane', 25],['Jennifer', 'Doe', 28]]

returns = ['Date', 'OrderNo'],['01/03/23', 39],['01/02/23', 28]]

Expected Result:

returned = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'OrderNo', 'Returned'],['John', 'Smith', 39, 'Y'],['Mary', 'Jane', 25, ''],['Jennifer', 'Doe', 28, 'Y']]

i tried python pandas isin and and an loop both didn't really work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
orders = [['First Name', 'Last Name', 'OrderNo'],['John', 'Smith', 39], 
['Mary', 'Jane', 25],['Jennifer', 'Doe', 28]]

returns = [['Date', 'OrderNo'],['01/03/23', 39],['01/02/23', 28]]
orders_df = pd.DataFrame(orders[1:], columns=orders[0])
returns_df = pd.DataFrame(returns[1:], columns=returns[0])
orders_df['Returned']=orders_df['OrderNo'].apply(lambda x:'Y' if x in 
list(returns_df['OrderNo']) else 'N')
print(orders_df)
```

output:

[image]